# Stored procedure join converted to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have a T-SQL stored procedure join which I need to convert to a MySQL join. I'm not sure of the exact syntax.

T-SQL code:

```
    SELECT username
    FROM wattsure..be_user_profiles bup
    JOIN wattsure..be_users bu
    ON bup.user_id = bu.id
    WHERE company_name = @installer
    AND [group] = 6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$param = mysql_real_escape_string($param); 
//at the least, or use PDO.

$query = "SELECT username
          FROM wattsure.be_user_profiles bup
          INNER JOIN wattsure.be_users bu
          ON bup.user_id = bu.id
          WHERE company_name = '$param' AND `group` = '6' ";
//Don't forget these quotes    ^      ^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT username FROM  wattsure.be_user_profiles bup
INNER JOIN wattsure.be_users bu
ON bup.user_id = bu.id
WHERE company_name = '$var'
AND `group` = 6
```

I hope wattsure is DB name....
Hope this helps...

Comment: Don't forget to quote $vars ! or syntax errors and SQL-injections will be your fate.